# after_create, belongs_to and validate_presence_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I have the following two classes, where class A initializes B in after_create. Unfortunately this does not work, and the creation of B fails due to violation of the presence_of validation:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bs

  after_create :after_create_hook

  def after_create_hook
    B.create(:a => self)
  end
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :a
  validates_presence_of :a
end
```

When creating an A, the A gets created, but not the B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this: http://blog.teksol.info/2006/03/08/don-t-validate-belongs_to-or-else

The mistake here is, to validate for an instance of a. As this is just a foreign key, the validation has to check for that:

```
validates_presence_of :a_id
```

And now things work.